After restarting Vector.dev How to send data stored in disk buffer?
I have a vector.toml file with the following contents:
    [sources.dummy_logs]
    type = "syslog"
    address = "0.0.0.0:9000"
    mode = "udp"

    [transforms.parse_logs_clickhouse]
    type = "remap"
    inputs = ["dummy_logs"]
    ...

    [transforms.parse_logs_s3]
    type = "remap"
    inputs = ["dummy_logs"]
    ...

    [sinks.s3]
    ...
    buffer.type = "disk"
    buffer.max_size = 30000000000  # 30 GB
    buffer.when_full = "drop_newest"

    [sinks.clickhouse]
    ...
    batch.timeout_secs = 1
    buffer.type = "memory"
    buffer.max_events = 3000000 # 2 GB
    buffer.when_full = "drop_newest"

Imagine the following scenario where both Clickhouse and S3 go down, and the data (logs/events) begins to accumulate in buffers—memory for Clickhouse, and disk for S3. What happens if Vector.dev also crashes? The data in memory will be lost forever, but the data on disk remains. After restarting Vector.dev, the data that remains on the disk does not get sent to S3. How can I send it there?
At first I wanted to find the answer in the documentation. But Vector.dev has quite a large documentation and I couldn't find the answer to my question in it. I also searched for the answer on the Internet, but I didn't find it there either

Consider using acks - meaning the data wont be counted as consumed from the source as long as the sinks didnt acknowledged the eventbhas been processed correctly
